# SQL Column Populating

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to know if it is possible to create another column in a table that has data that I wish to populate in this new column?  The new column is Flag2.  Here is the table:

[image]

what I want to do is, where item id is 30, I want the ITEM ID to only display 30 once and, populate the QC Unsupportted in Flag2?  How do I do this?

I can only think of doing an inner join but this is not working.

This is what I have done in trying to do so:

```
SELECT 
    A.ITEMID, A.FLAG1, A.FLAG2 
FROM 
    #FLAGS as A
INNER JOIN 
    #FLAGS as B ON A.ITEMID = B.ITEMID
GROUP BY 
    a.ITEMID, a.FLAG1, A.FLAG2
ORDER BY 
    ITEMID
```

Comment: ?!?! What exactly do you want to do?? Update your table and fill the `Flag2` column?? Or just select something? Not quite clear from your question....

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to query the table or update values in the table?  If you are trying to query the table, what do you want the result set to be when querying the example data you gave?

Comment: Jeff, I'm having a really hard time figuring out what you are doing and what you want to accomplish. Can you rewrite to be a little more clear?

Comment: I want to fill the Flag2 column when there is multiple flags per item id.  I do not want there to be duplicate id's based on flags.  So, where 30 is in the table, there are 2 of them, with 2 different flag values in flag1.  I want the second flag name to be put in flag2 and have it read with the itemid as 30, flag1 as onepage, flag2 as qcsupported.  I don't know if I have to do an update or create a view in order to actually do this?

Comment: @Jeff: how do you decide to "take the second item for itemid = 30" ?? What's the criteria?? The "second" sorted by what order??

Comment: flag2 is assigned by the itemid.  instead of having the items duplicated in the itemid column because of multiple names assigned to it in the flag1 column, I want the the multiple names spread out across the rows.  EXAMPLE: 30, onepage, qcunsupported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you are after, if the current FLAG1 values are distinct *for any ITEMID* and you only have at most two instances of the same ID, I think this should do what you want:

```
SELECT
    lft.ITEMID
  , lft.FLAG1
  , rght.FLAG1 FLAG2
FROM (
  SELECT
      t.ITEMID
    , t.FLAG1
  FROM (
    SELECT
        l.ITEMID
      , l.FLAG1
      , COUNT(l.ITEMID) i
    FROM #FLAGS l
      INNER JOIN #FLAGS r ON l.ITEMID = r.ITEMID
    WHERE r.FLAG1 <= l.FLAG1
    GROUP BY
        l.ITEMID
      , l.FLAG1) t
  WHERE t.i=1) lft
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT
      t.ITEMID
    , t.FLAG1
  FROM (
    SELECT
        l.ITEMID
      , l.FLAG1
      , COUNT(l.ITEMID) i
    FROM #FLAGS l
      INNER JOIN #FLAGS r ON l.ITEMID = r.ITEMID
    WHERE r.FLAG1 <= l.FLAG1
    GROUP BY
        l.ITEMID
      , l.FLAG1) t
WHERE t.i=2) rght ON lft.ITEMID = rght.ITEMID

-- Or better
SELECT
    lft.ITEMID
  , lft.FLAG1
  , rght.FLAG1 FLAG2
FROM (
  SELECT
      t.ITEMID
    , t.FLAG1
  FROM (
    SELECT
        l.ITEMID
      , l.FLAG1
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ITEMID ORDER BY FLAG1) as i
    FROM test l) t
  WHERE t.i=1) lft
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT
      t.ITEMID
    , t.FLAG1
  FROM (
    SELECT
        l.ITEMID
      , l.FLAG1
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ITEMID ORDER BY FLAG1) as i
    FROM test l) t
  WHERE t.i=2) rght ON lft.ITEMID = rght.ITEMID
```

If you have additional flag values for the same ID, a new outer join can be added to a new inline table (rght2, rght3, etc.) where i=3, 4, etc. and you are selecting rght2 AS FLAG3, rght3 AS FLAG4, etc.

Also note that the current values for FLAG1 will be distributed through FLAG1 and FLAG2 in alphabetical order. If you wanted to distribute them in reverse order you could replace <= with >=. If you had more than two flags that you wanted distributed in a specific order, you would have to create a separate table with a ranking value and join to that which would be doable but even uglier!

Comment: I will try this out and let you know.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it worked but I did want to add that since you're using at least SQLS2005, you can use ROW_NUMBER() instead of the self join to generate the i column. That would be prefered, especially for a large table. Both instances of the inline tabe t can be reduced to: `(SELECT l.ITEMID, l.FLAG1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ITEMID ORDER BY FLAG1) as i FROM test l) t` I will modify the original post for clarity.